# How to read a stream size in Gstreamer?

Tags: python, audio, gstreamer, pygobject, gobject-introspection

## 1. Context

I have a very simple pipeline:

```
filesrc location=foo.wav ! decodebin ! ENCODER ! MUXER ! filesink location=bar.whatever
```

with `ENCODER` being any `gstreamer` encoder and `MUXER`, whatever suitable muxer. The pipeline is working. For the sake of simplicity, **assume there is only one audio stream coming from `decodebin`**.

## 2. Problem

Now,

- How can I query the total audio stream size *in bytes*, right after `decodebin` (i.e. the raw PCM size)?
- How can I query the total audio stream size *in bytes*, right after `ENCODER` (i.e. the raw compressed size)?

## 3. What I tried

I am using Python with GI. I've tried with the `appsink` element, to no avail, with the following pipeline:

```
filesrc location=foo.wav ! decodebin ! ENCODER ! tee name=tee \
      tee. ! queue ! MUXER ! filesink location=bar.whatever \
      tee. ! queue ! appsink
```

---

The relevant part with `appsink` is the following:

```
counter = 0
appsink = Gst.ElementFactory.make('appsink', None)
appsink.set_property('emit-signals', True)
appsink.set_property('sync', False)
appsink.connect('new-sample', on_new_buffer)
appsink.connect('new-preroll', on_new_preroll)

def on_new_buffer(sample):
    counter += sample.emit('pull-sample').get_buffer().get_size() 

def on_new_preroll(sample):
    counter += sample.emit('pull-preroll').get_buffer().get_size()
```

However this is really really slow (20x slower than just using `filesink`).

Comment: 20x slower is a lot, did you try tracking what exactly is consuming all that extra time? Perhaps it can be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using pad probes.

http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstPad.html#gst-pad-add-probe

Add a pad probe for buffers and buffer lists on the pads where you want to count the number of bytes.

Comment: I'd also suggest considering using `identity` elements.  I find them to be a bit easier to hook onto than pads, especially dynamically created pads off a decodebin.